# Generalization to higher moments of the survival function method for computing the first moment.

Tags: probability

If $X$ is a nonnegative random variable, we may compute the first moment by integrating the survival function:

$$ E(X) = \int_0^\infty S_X(x) \, dx $$

Is there a reasonable generalization of this for computing higher moments?

Comment: What is $S_X(x)$ here?

Comment: The survival function of X:  $S_X(x) = P(X > x)$

Comment: [Here's calculating the 2nd moment](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/143790/second-moment-from-survival-function)

Comment: Thanks.  That's for a continuous variable only.  I just learned about a more general version here: https://www.degruyter.com/downloadpdf/j/tmmp.2012.52.issue-1/v10127-012-0025-9/v10127-012-0025-9.xml

Comment: @BarrySmith I know this is an old post. But the link you have is not working. Do you think you can tell us what the general version of this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\mathbb E[X^n] = \int_0^{\infty} S_{X^n}(t) dt\overset{\displaystyle\overset{t:=x^n}\downarrow}= \int_0^{\infty} n x^{n-1} S_{X^n}(x^n) dx = \int_0^{\infty} n x^{n-1} S_X (x) dx$$ where $S_{X^n}(t)=P(X^n\ge t)$.